# Reduce border padding on button in header

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a button on my wordpress site titled 'try apptive free' in my header with a 2px border around it. The border already inherits a 10px padding. I want to bring the padding down to 5px to shrink the border distance however, changing the padding movies the 'try apptive free' out of line with the logo on the left side of the header titled 'Apptive'.

Is there an easy way to change the padding to 5px without moving the button out of line with the logo?

www.allaboutcats.wordpress.com

Comment: I don't see a logo on the button. Can you make a snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: The logo isn't on the button, it is on the left side on the page titled 'Apptive'. I wasn't clear, I will edit my post to clarify. I will try and create a snippet in a moment.

Comment: But that's on the other side of the screen. I wouldn't notice if those weren't aligned. Honestly.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You could always add some `margin` to it, to compensate for the removed padding. Or you could place both elements in one container and give them `vertical-align: middle`.

Comment: The margin was a great solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a `margin-top: 5px;` It should work.

Comment: This solved it with some trial and error. Thank you.